# How do I make a slider image a % of the browser window size with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've tried searching here and many other places to come up with a solution to this, but can't seem to find anything yet. Essentially I have an image that is around 1800px wide by 500px in height. I need this image to fit all resolutions. Rather instead of being displayed as a certain with, it needs to be displayed as a percentage of the browser window size.

Ideally having it take up 80% of the width of the browser window...

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this with jQuery. Mostly it would be dependent on the size of the browser window when it first opens. It does't necessarily have to get smaller and smaller if someone decides to shrink the window size of their browser..

I know it's an odd ball one, so any help would be much appreicated!

Comment: Have you tried: $("img").css({"width":"80%"}); ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty effectively in CSS:

```
#image {
  width: 80%;
  content: url('./pinkfloyd.gif');
}
```

Alternatively, If it has to be done in jQuery, You can use [fullbg](http://bavotasan.com/demos/fullbg/)

Comment: Hrmm, I tried using your code but the background image doesn't show up at all. If I switch the CSS to background: url('./whatever.gif'); it shows fine. It it was big image (1920x 500px) or something like that, and so needs to shrink in both width and height?  Any ideas why the content CSS isn't showing the background image yet the background tag is?